# Can I include Python implementation of class method saved in another file

Tags: python, class, methods, conventions

In Python, we cannot save class method's definition outside of class definition itself (as I understand it)  because there is no concept of declaration. However, I wonder whether it is possible that I can include source code of method implementation saved in a standalone file, namely having the interpreter replace the piece of code in question. But as I have never seen such thing, this is probably not idiomatic in Python. Then how do you deal with the irritation that a class definition will be extremely long? Please correct me since I am new to Python, and find it quite different from C++.

```
class Foo
   def bar():
      # How to include definition saved in another file?
```

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864366/are-classes-in-python-in-different-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do!

### First solution

#### bar.py

```
def bar(foo):
    print foo
```

#### foo.py

```
from bar import bar as foo_bar

class Foo:
    bar = foo_bar
```

---

### Alternative solution

#### bar.py

```
def bar(foo):
    print foo
```

#### foo.py

```
from bar import bar as foo_bar

class Foo:
    def bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return foo_bar(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import another_file

class Foo
   def bar():
      another_file.class_name/def_name ...
```

or import just particular definition

```
from another_file import def_name

class Foo
   def bar():
      def_name ...
```